# Table TD width not working

Tags: html, css

I am making dropdown menu and apparently I can't change the width I tried different methods. I want each column to have width 200px but it doesn't work.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-image: url("../sliki/meni.png");
  width: 220px;
  height: 60px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {} #uslugibn {
  background-image: url("../sliki/banner.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
#meninav {
  background-color: #41c2ac;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}
#meninav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
  <button class="dropbtn"></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:200px;">
          <a href="#">Берово</a>
          <a href="#">Битола</a>
          <a href="#">Богданци</a>
          <a href="#">Валандово</a>
          <a href="#">Велес</a>
          <a href="#">Виница</a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:200px;">
          <a href="#">Гевгелија</a>
          <a href="#">Гостивар</a>
          <a href="#">Дебар</a>
          <a href="#">Делчево</a>
          <a href="#">Демир Капија</a>
          <a href="#">Демир Хисар</a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:200px;">
          <a href="#">Кавадарци</a>
          <a href="#">Кичево</a>
          <a href="#">Кочани</a>
          <a href="#">Кратово</a>
          <a href="#">Крива Паланка</a>
          <a href="#">Куманово</a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:200px;">
          <a href="#">Крушево</a>
          <a href="#">Македоснки Брод</a>
          <a href="#">Македонска Каменица</a>
          <a href="#">Неготино</a>
          <a href="#">Охрид</a>
          <a href="#">Пехчево</a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:200px;">
          <a href="#">Прилеп</a>
          <a href="#">Пробиштип</a>
          <a href="#">Радовиш</a>
          <a href="#">Ресен</a>
          <a href="#">Свети Николе</a>
          <a href="#"><strong>Скопје</strong></a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:200px;">
          <a href="#">Струга</a>
          <a href="#">Струмица</a>
          <a href="#">Тетово</a>
          <a href="#">Штип</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like 200px to me: https://jsfiddle.net/vvr6hLgo/ There is probably something else interfering here. Can you set up a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: The columns do have a `200px` width as far as I can see.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what browser are you guys using? I'm in chrome 46, and mine are definitely not 200px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the width to the anchor inside the td and it works.

```
td > a {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1vkfg9nb/

Answer (score 6):

When your table is not respecting widths, it's almost better to apply it on a cell-by-cell basis. But this quick fix always seems to work for me:

```
table{
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}
```

**[Working fiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/nmxf83bf/)**

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already contain the solution.
To explain why this happens: tables always try to fit as much content as they can in the space that they have. Even if this means ignoring the rules, such as `width`.

Now in this case, the table's parent is positioned absolutely, so its width doesn't count. That means the table's grandparent div only (effectively) contains the 220px wide button and it therefore itself only 220px wide, being an inline-block.

So... that is the width of the table's container and that's what it tries to squeeze itself into. That's why it chooses to ignore its width properties and only makes itself as wide as its contents; it already overflows its container as it is.